# View individual artists in compilation albums?

Tags: itunes, ipad, music.app

I can't seem to set up my music collection so that when opening a compilation album on my iPad it shows a list of songs on the compilation album along with the artist of each song.

In iTunes on my computer it displays as expected - the song name appears with the artist below it in the compilations album:

[image: Display in itunes on macbook]

When synced to my iPad and clicking on the same compilation album it displays without the artist name:

[image: Display in music on ipad]

Note also that the album artist name below the album thumbnail is one of the track artists.

The settings for this album in iTunes on my Mac are:

- Each song has their artist name and song name completed.
- Album artist is left blank
- Compilation is ticked.

Why are the results correct in iTunes on the computer, but not on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I've written “Various Artists” in the Album Artist field, and ticked the Compilations box. It works fine for me in iTunes, on my iPad, iPhone, iPod nano and my ATV. So my suggestion is to try write something in the Album Artist field.

Comment: Typically, after posting my question I stumbled across a solution that almost solves my problem, but not completely.

I completely closed the music app on the ipad then reopened it and all the artists did appear under their track names in compilations.

I have added various artists under the album artist too.

The only problem that remains is rather than displaying "Various Artists" under the thumbnail in picture 2 above, it shows a random artist name. Do you get the correct album artist displaying here?

Comment: I only looked at the album list, and there it shows Various Artists under the thumb, but not when opening the album. Then it, as for you, shows a random artist name from the album. It also shows a random artist name for an album mixed by a MOS-DJ, his name is in the album artist field, but each track still has it own track artist. This has to be a bug in iOS for the iPad, as I don't seem to have the same problem with my iPhone.